# Container exits with the following message docker container exited with code 0

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Hi I am new to docker and docker-compose.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: "2.1"
services:
  licenseserver:
   build:
    context: ./licenseserver
    dockerfile: .dockerfile
   ports:
       - "20000:20000"
   mac_address: C8-D9-D2-A5-8F-DE
   hostname: idol
```

dockerfile contents

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN mkdir /opt/MicroFocus

WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus
ADD LicenseServer.zip /opt/MicroFocus
RUN chmod 777 LicenseServer.zip
RUN unzip LicenseServer.zip
RUN rm -f LicenseServer.zip


WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus/LicenseServer_12.5.0_LINUX_X86_64
ADD idol.dat /opt/MicroFocus/LicenseServer_12.5.0_LINUX_X86_64
RUN ls -lart
RUN pwd
RUN ./start-licenseserver.sh
```

docker-compose build works fine, but when I run docker-compose up I get the following. How do I ensure that the container continues to run.

```
root@development-vm:/home/vinay/docker/AT# docker-compose up
Starting at_licenseserver_1 ... done
Attaching to at_licenseserver_1
at_licenseserver_1 exited with code 0
root@development-vm:/home/vinay/docker/AT# docker-compose exec licenseserver bash
ERROR: No container found for licenseserver_1
```

The contents of start-licenseserver.sh is as follows

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:../bin:./ffmpeg:./filters:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
clear
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "Micro Focus License Server"
echo "(c) 1999-2018 Micro Focus"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
echo "This script will start License Server"
echo "(licenseserver.exe)"
echo ""
echo "Hit return to continue"
echo "Hit Ctrl-C to end this script now!"
echo "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
read DUMMY
echo "Starting License Server..."
chmod u+x licenseserver.exe
nohup $PWD/licenseserver.exe > licenseserver.out 2> licenseserver.err &
serverpid=$!
echo "Started License Server with PID $serverpid"
exit
```

Comment: It happened to me when I ran out of disk space. Try pruning and see if it solves it ‘docker system prune’

Comment: Try interchanging these two lines.`COPY LicenseServer.zip /opt/MicroFocus` then `WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus`

Comment: @AmirImani docker systme prune didn't make a difference.

Comment: But how is it that docker ps shows no running images. ./start-licenseserver.sh should start a service in the background

Comment: what do you get from `RUN ls -lart`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your Dockerfile to have a `CMD` command not `RUN`, `RUN`  command used only while building docker image. docker expects you container to have [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or a [command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) to be run and it must be a background process, e.g web server.
check this [article](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) about the difference about `RUN`, `CMD` and `entrypoint`
Change your Dockerfile to this and try to run it again:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install unzip
RUN mkdir /opt/MicroFocus

WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus
ADD LicenseServer.zip /opt/MicroFocus
RUN chmod 777 LicenseServer.zip
RUN unzip LicenseServer.zip
RUN rm -f LicenseServer.zip


WORKDIR /opt/MicroFocus/LicenseServer_12.5.0_LINUX_X86_64
ADD idol.dat /opt/MicroFocus/LicenseServer_12.5.0_LINUX_X86_64
RUN ls -lart
RUN pwd
CMD ["start-licenseserver.sh"]
```

Comment: ok that helped.  But now I am getting ERROR: for e6e3c75ca623_at_licenseserver_1  Cannot start service licenseserver: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"start-licenserver.sh\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: ok try to change the command to`CMD ["/opt/MicroFocus/start-licenseserver.sh"]` I guess this is the full, the error shows that container not able to see the executable, so that should fix it, let me know if it worked so that I update my answer.

Comment: It was a permissioning issue. I chmod 777 the script and it works now

Comment: But the container still exits

Comment: exit 0 means, the process stoped with no error, are you sure that the script run a background service?

Comment: I have updated the contents of the start-licenseserver.sh script. Its designed to run as a service in the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214391/discussion-between-vinay-joseph-and-root).

Comment: The issue is clear to me here, not sure how to make this script not to exit, you are running the service as a sub process then you tell it to exit, thats why it keep stoping, I'm not expert in `powershell` but try to remove `> licenseserver.out 2> licenseserver.err & serverpid=$!` along with the exit and let me know what happens when you run it like this.